# Xmobar not visible when using with Xmonad

Tags: linux, haskell, xmonad

Today I've started with Xmonad and can not get Xmobar to be visible on top of layouts
At my `.xmobarrc` I has these code:

```
...
   , position =     TopW L 100
   , lowerOnStart =     True
   , hideOnStart =      False
   , allDesktops =      True
   , overrideRedirect = True
   , pickBroadest =     False
   , persistent =       True

...
```

And this is my `xmonad.hs`:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)
import System.IO

main = do
  xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar"
  xmonad $ defaultConfig
    { manageHook = manageDocks <+> manageHook defaultConfig
    , layoutHook = avoidStruts  $  layoutHook defaultConfig
    , logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
                    { ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc
                    , ppTitle = xmobarColor "green" "" . shorten 50
                    }
    , terminal = "urxvt"
    , modMask = mod4Mask
    }
```

Xmobar is running with Xmonad but it's not visible. How can I solve it?
I need that Xmobar always be visible at the top of monitor.

Comment: I think some parts of the strut support have moved into the EWMH module. Can you try importing `XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops` and changing the xmonad invocation to `xmonad . ewmh $ def ...`? If that works, I'm happy to throw it in an answer. If not, my next test would be to check that xmobar is asking for the right amount of space by running `xprop | grep _NET_WM_STRUT` and clicking on xmobar.

Comment: It must looks like this? https://gist.github.com/cryptomaniac512/3718cb18498f723c545794b7b4e74b1c

Comment: That looks right to me. Does it work?

Comment: No( Xmobar works, but hidden by other windows.

Comment: Then... did you run my proposed next test? What did it say?

Comment: When I run `xprop | grep _NET_WM_STRUT` I get this output:
`_NET_WM_STRUT(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 21, 0`
`_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1919, 0, 0`

Comment: Those struts look right to me. Does this happen on all workspaces? Does it persist if you reload the layout? (By default, mod+shift+space will reload the layout.)

Comment: Yes. No changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution founded at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288037/

I add this `handleEventHook = handleEventHook defaultConfig <+> docksEventHook` and now Xmobar always visible.

Answer (score 0):

Although many of the other solutions posted are also important, I had to add `lowerOnStart = False` to .xmobarrc, so it isn't sent to the bottom of the window stack on start.